# Internal server error 500 when making POST request to server

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose

I am trying to make a social media app project using React and MongoDB but whenever I am trying to register a user I get a POST error from the console. I tried checking my client-side and server-side code but I still can't get the user info to post and register.

**EDIT **
Thank you for the tips on how to make a better question here is my second attempt at a more clear post

The main error I'm getting in the console is this:

```
> POST http://localhost:3001/auth/register 500 (Internal Server Error)
> register  @   Form.jsx:56 handleFormSubmit    @   Form.jsx:89
> (anonymous)   @   Formik.tsx:849 (anonymous)  @   Formik.tsx:1200
> (anonymous)   @   Formik.tsx:756 Promise.then (async)     
> (anonymous)   @   Formik.tsx:731 (anonymous)  @   Formik.tsx:1200
> (anonymous)   @   Formik.tsx:823 (anonymous)  @   Formik.tsx:1200
> callCallback  @   react-dom.development.js:4164
> invokeGuardedCallbackDev  @   react-dom.development.js:4213
> invokeGuardedCallback @   react-dom.development.js:4277
> invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError   @   react-dom.development.js:4291
> executeDispatch   @   react-dom.development.js:9041
> processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder  @   react-dom.development.js:9073
> processDispatchQueue  @   react-dom.development.js:9086
> dispatchEventsForPlugins  @   react-dom.development.js:9097
> (anonymous)   @   react-dom.development.js:9288
> batchedUpdates$1  @   react-dom.development.js:26140
> batchedUpdates    @   react-dom.development.js:3991
> dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem @   react-dom.development.js:9287
> dispatchEventWithEnableCapturePhaseSelectiveHydrationWithoutDiscreteEventReplay   @   react-dom.development.js:6465
> dispatchEvent @   react-dom.development.js:6457 dispatchDiscreteEvent
```

Upon further examination of the error through the browser console it is pointing me to this line of code in my Form.jsx file:

```
const savedUserResponse = await fetch("http://localhost:3001/auth/register", {
      method: "POST",
      body: formData,
    });
```

This is the full block of code for my register function:

```
const register = async (values, onSubmitProps) => {
    //send form info with an image
    const formData = new FormData();
    for (let value in values) {
      formData.append(value, values[value]);
    }
    formData.append("picturePath", values.picture.name);

    const savedUserResponse = await fetch("http://localhost:3001/auth/register", {
      method: "POST",
      body: formData,
    });
    const savedUser = await savedUserResponse.json();
    onSubmitProps.resetForm();

    if (savedUser) {
      setPageType("login");
    }
  };
```

In my server side code this is the index.js that handles the auth:

```
// ROUTES WITH FILES
app.post("/auth/register", upload.single("picture"), register);
app.post("/posts", verifyToken, upload.single("picture"), createPost);

//ROUTES
app.use("/auth", authRoutes);
app.use("/users", userRoutes);
app.use("/posts", postRoutes);

// MONGOOSE
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 6001;
mongoose.set("strictQuery", false);
mongoose
  .connect(process.env.MONGO_URL, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  })
  .then(() => {
    app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server Port: ${PORT}`));

    // User.insertMany(users);
    // Post.insertMany(posts);
  })
  .catch((error) => console.log(`${error} did not connect`));
```

Register function from my auth.js in my controllers folder:

```
export const register = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { firstName, lastName, email, password, picturePath, friends, location, occupation } = req.body;

    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt();
    const passwordHash = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt);

    const newUser = new User({
      firstName,
      lastName,
      email,
      password: passwordHash,
      picturePath,
      friends,
      location,
      occupation,
      viewedProfile: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000),
      impressions: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000),
    });
    const savedUser = await newUser.save();
    res.status(201).json(savedUser);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({ error: err.message });
  }
};
```

The response I get from the server :

```
"POST /auth/register HTTP/1.1" 500 248
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'G:\WebDev\DesTracker\destracker-app\server\public,assets\p2.jpeg'
```

I'm expecting the user info to post to my database after I click register but instead I'm getting the interal server error 500

Comment: hey mate, welcome to stackoverflow! please produce a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). it's unlikely you'll get assistance otherwise. Attach only relevant code, and the full errors you get, both in the developer console and (if possible) server logs.

Comment: okay thanks for the advice should i just make a new post then?

Comment: Or edit this one. Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page.

Comment: @Phil I've added the register function in the post above.

Comment: @Phil sorry, added now thanks for the responses

Comment: The error hints at a Multer configuration issue. Looks like a probable typo in your disk storage destination path.

Comment: Great job with the edit! Now we can figure stuff out. like Phil said, it's trying to read a non-existent file. `public,assets` really feels like it's actually `public/assets`. Line 38 in `server/index.js`.

Comment: @Yarin_007 It was exactly that a "," instead of a "/". Thank you so much for the post tips and responses. Appreciated greatly.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to provide more information to get the best answer as @Yarin_007
said. However, I'll try to provide assistance with the minimal info provided.

A status 500 simply means you have an exception or an error on your server. Now, the warning has provided Where the error is, why you're getting that error and what the error is.

Where: You can find the error in the submitForm().

What: It is a SyntaxError which simply means you have deviated from the syntax of a sequence of characters or tokens of a programming language.

Why: We say so because '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON.

This is the explanation of the error based on the information you provided. Get us more details about the error so we can help.

Happy coding!!!

Comment: Thank you for the response, I tried to provide some more context and code in my problem. I think the syntax error is stemming from the Internal server error.